# In Django Web Project, my app is not recognized

Tags: python, django

I'm new in Python & Django.

I am creating a new app using Python 3.6 Django 2.2.7 and for some reason, the `url.py` which holds the urlpatterns of the project, is not recognizing the `urls.py` of my new app (`ManageMissingBusinesses`).

Please see below the relevant urls.py (on the project level).

**urls.py (project level)**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from app import forms
from datetime import datetime

import app.forms
import app.views

urlpatterns = [
    path 
('ManageMissingBusinesses/',include('ManageMissingBusinesses.urls'))
]
```

The urls.py on the project level is located on level above the `ManageMissingBusinesses` module/directory.

While starting the server, I'm receiving an error on the urlpattern line:

```
path ('ManageMissingBusinesses/',include('ManageMissingBusinesses.urls'))
```

> ModuleNotFoundError:No module named 'ManageMissingBusinesses'

Can you explain me what is the issue?

Comment: Have you installed `ManageMissingBusinesses` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` block of the `settings.py`?

Comment: Yes, I did, please see my comments for the second answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to resolve the issue.

My problem was that my app directory was created using MS Visual Studio which has created a project under two directories having the same name (not sure what is the reason).

So the directories tree looks like:

Proj1 (visual studio files like sln file)
--Proj1 (where manage.py exists)
----Proj1 (where setting.py exists)
------myapp (the module name)

So I added the Proj1.myapp to the setting.py and the url.py files which solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Go to YourProjectDir\settings.py and include your created app `ManageMissingBusinesses` into the installed apps like so:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ManageMissingBusinesses'
]
```

For further reference take a look into https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial02/

Comment: Thanks Phanti, Yes, I did it, but as I got same error also after doing so (in previous step), I removed it. now I added it again and my failure is during the project rebuild (using "Migrate"). getting the following   
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ManageMissingBusinesses'
Done building project "BankAccountUI.pyproj" -- FAILED.

Comment: Project rebuild (Using "Manage" not "Migrate") - sorry for the typo.